# Why does this command fail to print the correct exit code of a Python command?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, exit-code, errorlevel

In a cmd.exe window, when I run `python -c "exit(12)"` and then run `echo %errorlevel%`, it prints `12`. After that, when I run `python -c "exit(13)" & echo %errorlevel%`, it prints `12`.

Why does  the second command fail to print the correct exit code?

Comment: Both commands are being run within the same environment context. If you won't use the `&` operator and run them in sequence it will produce the expected value. Python is irrelevant here.

Comment: @BartoszKP Actually I need to use Python because I am trying to solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555044/why-sometimes-python-subprocess-failed-to-get-the-correct-exit-code-after-runnin).

Comment: It's irrelevant what *you* are trying to solve. In *this question* Python is irrelevant, as it concerns only the way *cmd* works. I didn't want to edit it out though, as it seems too much, but the question would be more helpful to others if you made it more general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution of %errorlevel% happens when you run the command. It reflects the value of %errorlevel% when you pressed your 'enter' key.

As an example consider:

```
> set foo=foo

> echo %foo%
foo

> set foo=bar & echo %foo%
foo

> echo %foo%
bar
```

You can check the errorlevel like this however:

```
> python -c 'exit(13)' & if errorlevel 13 echo "its 13"
```