# WINDOWS - python subprocess returns incorrect shell script exit code

Tags: python, windows, bash, subprocess, exit-code

Hi folks I'm a scripting/python newbie but i have searched endlessly for a solution to no avail.

I am trying to call a sh script (using windows 10) using python (subprocess) and return the exit code to python.

For clarity i have stripped out everything except the relevant code.

I have an sh script 'return_value.sh' which literally has one line to set an exit code:

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 9
```

I can run this via git-bash and it returns exit_code 9 as expected.

When i try to call this from python however, it always returns zero:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe','return_value.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
out, err = p.communicate()
print (p.returncode)
```

I've searched for ages and cannot find a resolution.  The closest i could find was:

[Why sometimes Python subprocess failed to get the correct exit code after running a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555044/why-sometimes-python-subprocess-failed-to-get-the-correct-exit-code-after-runnin)

but it didnt help me.  Can anyone please give me some advice?

Many thanks

Mike

Comment: Why `shell=True` if you are passing a list as the first argument?

Comment: Why `shell=True` *ever*? On UNIX, a shell will return the exit status of the last command it ran, but as a UNIX person, I have no idea of whether that's also true on Windows; if it's not, well, there's your problem.

Comment: Also note that the shell created with `shell=True` is *not* the shell you want to have invoked to execute your program; they're very different things.

Comment: [This page](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) describes cmd.exe `%errorlevel%` and how some commands will overwrite it, some will overwrite it on error only, and some will never modify it, and additionally that "In most cases the ERRORLEVEL will be the same as the exit code, but there are a few buggy cases where this fails.". So yeah, definitely try without the shell....

Comment: subprocess `shell=True` uses the Windows `%ComSpec%` shell, which is almost always cmd.exe. If CMD can run "return_value.sh", it's via `ShellExecuteEx` using the registered "open" action for ".sh" files. That depends on your system configuration. Add some `sleep` or other delay in the script, and inspect the process tree in Process Explorer or `pslist -t`. If there are intermediate or orphaned processes, then CMD's exit code (from `cmd.exe /c "return_value.sh"`) probably isn't from the process that actually executes the script.

Comment: Also, don't use an args list with `shell=True`. This is documented, but admittedly the subprocess docs are an eyesore.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far.  I've removed shell=True so it should default to false.  Since its calling a sh script, i dont think it can run from cmd, it needs something like gitbash.  So i have added the path to gitbash in the argument list.  

`p = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe', 'return_value.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

It still returns zero which is incorrect. I have checked that the script returns 9 by calling it from gitbash interactively (using sh command) then typing echo $? which returns 9.  Any more ideas on why this isnt working? I'll try on linux